# Moments of merit

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

The merit of a prime gap equals $(p_{n+1}-p_n)/\ln p_n$.  One can interrogate the statistics of merit by first restricting $n<M$ for some $M$, and then letting $M$ approach $\infty$.  The very definition got rigged to make the mean of merit equal 1 in the limit.  What about higher moments?  Do we have theorems, standard conjectures, or even just numerical evidence concerning their values or their mere existence?

Comment: I don't think "merit" is a term commonly used for this concept; "normalized prime gap" is common and quite descriptive.

Comment: I picked up the term from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap

Comment: There is also the Cramér–Shanks–Granville ratio, a candidate for a *different* normalized prime gap.

Comment: Maybe the quantity defined by  $ \log g_{n}/\log\log n $  where  $ g_{n}=p_{n+1}-p_{n} $ can be of interest too.

Comment: @sylvain-julien Or perhaps $g_n/(\ln n)^2$.  The heuristic: if x has primeness probability $1/\ln x$, then $\ln x$ consecutive composites starting at x should happen with probability about $(1 - 1/\ln x)^{\ln x}$, so $1/e$ in the limit.  $c(\ln x)^2$ consecutive composites would occur with probability $1/e^{c\ln x}= 1/x^c$ making the expected number of occurrences finite for $c>1$.   Thus one might expect a bound for my proposed quantity and even ask whether a particular gap realizes a maximum value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard conjecture is that the statistics of $(p_{n+1}-p_n)/\ln n$ are, in the limit, precisely an exponential distribution with parameter $1$; one can recover conjectures about individual moments from this, although evaluating the moments is the natural way to approach the conjecture. This is the natural heuristic that follows from the model that every integer $m$ is prime with probability $1/\ln m$. I believe this conjecture was proved conditionally by [Gallagher (in Mathematika in 1976)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=409385), assuming a strong form of the prime $k$-tuples conjecture.

Comment: Moreover, a similar Poisson distribution should hold for successive twin primes, successive primes of the from $n^2+1$, etc, etc...

Comment: One must be a tiny bit careful:  Indeed the distribution should be Poisson, but the moments could blow up if there is an unusually large prime gap.  Gallagher's result, just to be precise, is based on the moments of $\pi(x+\lambda \log x)-\pi(x)$, which has the advantage of not being able to blow up!

Comment: Thanks Lucia for pointing out that pitfall when translating Gallagher's work to this situation!

Comment: Greg Martin -- Actually I'm confused. A Poisson distribution is a distribution on the counting numbers. If $π(x+\ln x)−π(x)$ is Poisson, wouldn't that mean that an exponential distribution governs merit? So the moments should be 1,2,6,24,...?? (Which doesn't jive with my calculations by the way.)

Comment: I accepted this answer...but don't you mean an exponential distribution??